# Is it reliable to assemble md from two machines at the same time

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid, md

Say we have the same disks accessible from two machines. I want to do assembling md from two machines. Is it possible/reliable ?

The disks are connected through SAS. All I need to have is reliable disk, in this case using md and two disks. I will do raw read/write to the raid, so filesystem is not important for me. I'm not sure about correct work of md here.

Comment: It would mess up badly.

Comment: How are the disks connected to the two machines? If via scsi, then the scsi layers should be fine with it, but the file-system layer will usually not: If you try to assess the disk from two or more machines as SAME time you will get file-system inconsistencies. I think it may be theoretically possible to have a special file system to do it.

Comment: Forget the filesystem layer, the md layer itself is not fine with it. At least not in a standard setup. Maybe it could work for `--build` (raid without metadata that never syncs), I don't know. Maybe you should ask the devs on linux-raid mailing list for this.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will ask them. Thanks.